# SELECT с UPDATE результата

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, update

есть таблица amortization с полем security_id
и таблица security с поями security_id и source_id.

нужно сделать выгрузку из таблицы amortization, **заменив** в выгрузке значение столбца security_id на source_id из таблицы security.

такой запрос возвращает source_id  по amortization. security_id.

```
SELECT source_id FROM security WHERE security_id = (SELECT TOP (1) security_id FROM amortization);
```

мне нужно использовать этот source_id место security_id в результате запроса

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM amortization;
```

как это можно осуществить?

select из таблицы amortization
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а select из таблицы security по запросу

```
SELECT * FROM sf_dm.sf_dm.[security] WHERE security_id = (SELECT TOP (1) security_id FROM sf_dm.sf_dm.amortization);
```

вернул [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в итоговой выборке security_id (56916) должен быть заменен на source_id(6462).

Comment: словами получилось описать не очень, давайте на примерах данных лучше. Звучит как обычный join. но top не ясно к чему ( и как отсортирован). но можно вытащить под запросом например если там множество строк соответствует.

Comment: дополнил примером выборки

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал в T-SQL'е но в postgresql должно работать.

```
SELECT sec.source_id, am.date, am.procent, am.amount_per_bond, am.number
FROM dbo.amortization AS am LEFT JOIN
dbo.security AS sec ON am.security_id = sec.security_id;
```